# Kafka console consumer: How to get only the last N messages from a topic instead of everything from the beginning?

Tags: apache-kafka

I can do this:

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --zookeeper 10.0.0.225:2181/kafka
--topic myTopic --property schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.100:8081 
--from-beginning
```

But I have too many messages. I would rather only get the last N ones. How can I do that with kafka console consumer?

Comment: just discard `--from-beginning` and rerun it for a while and then ctrl+c to interrupt the console consumer. You'd better redirect the result to a temp file.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to stick with the bundled binaries, you need to use the simple consumer shell:

```
bin/kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --broker-list mybroker:9092 --topic
mytopic --partition mypartition --offset myoffset
```

I recommend [kt](https://github.com/fgeller/kt); it's much faster, more lightweight and has better options.

Comment: the problem is that we have to specify the partition but the data may come in any partition

Answer (score 10):

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka.internal:9093 \
--max-messages 1 --group basan_PERF_console \
--consumer.config config-stage.properties \
--partition 1 --offset 14677669 \
--topic order-demandh
```

This is the way to retrieve one message at a time from specific offset

Comment: Add some description of what you're purposing.

Comment: Thank you for this. The --max-messages option is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just getting started with Kafka, so there may be a better way to do this, but it prints the last 10 messages from the first partition returned by `kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`, then continues to output new messages as they come in.

```
offsets=$(kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
  --broker-list $BROKER_1:9092,$BROKER_2:9092 --topic my_topic)
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server $BROKER_1:9092 \
  --topic my_topic \
  --partition $(echo $offsets | awk -F':' '{print $2}') \
  --offset $(($(echo $offsets | awk -F':| ' '{print $3}') - 10)) \
  --property schema.registry.url=http://$WORKER_1:8081
```

Replace the `10` above with the desired number of messages to print.

Comment: The one bug in your script is that it seems to assume you only have one partition. If you have multiple partitions, `$offsets` is multiple lines, which causes the command to fail.

Comment: The command doesn't fail, but it only uses the first partiton, so only the last N messages of partition 0 will be shown. I recommend using kafkacat with the -o -10 option.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the tool `kafkacat` which is documented for example [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html).

This is a very powerful and fast tool to read data out of Kafka from the console and is open source: https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat.

Many exmples are provided on GitHub and one example is shown below to read the last n (here: 2000) messages out of the partition 0 of topic 'mytopic':

```
kafkacat -C -b mybroker -t mytopic -p 0 -o -2000
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the `max-messages` argument can be passed to both the `kafka-console-consumer` and `kafka-avro-console-consumer` cli tools.

Because I've had to look a lot of this stuff individually, the below example uses the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` to consume the first 10 Avro records, from an SSL enabled topic, with schema registry configured, and prints the String keys along with the records.

```
./kafka-avro-console-consumer \
--bootstrap-server something.com:9093,something2.com:9093 \
--consumer.config /path/to/client-ssl.properties \
--property schema.registry.url=http://some-schema-registry.com \
--property print.key=true \
--key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer \
--from-beginning \
--max-messages 10 \
--topic some-topic-name
```

Comment: OP is asking about most recent N messages, not first N messages.

Answer (score 1):

First get the offset value in all partitions:

```
kafka-run-class.bat kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topicName
```

topicName:0:15
topicName:1:16
topicName:2:10

Now get the N number of messages from the particular topic and partition.
I used offset number as 10 because I want to read only 5 messages from partition-0.

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topicName --offset 10 --partition 0
```

It'll print last 5 messages from partition-0.

Remember Kafka does not guarantee ordering of messages between partitions. It does provide ordering within a partition.