# How to temporarily resume Spring Kafka listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am maintaining a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Kafka for a variety of asynchronous flows. I have implemented functionality that allows for me to dynamically pause and resume any Kafka Listener / consumer of my choosing. However, I would like to be able to resume a listener / consumer in a way such that it only temporarily polls a specified fixed number of Kafka messages (e.g. 1 or 5) such that I can safely test the business logic of the listener before opening / resuming it completely. What would be a natural way of doing this?

Comment: hmm not sure if there is a way, I would suggest you add a counter to consume only N amount of messages, then use your (pause functionality) afterwards.  You could also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983405/kafka-console-consumer-how-to-get-only-the-last-n-messages-from-a-topic-instead as You can figure out how many messages are in your partition, and seek to read only specific ones by using offset.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (2.8) allows you to fetch individual (or a group) of messages using the `KafkaTemplate` instead of a message-driven approach.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-template-receive